# Easiest way to create buffer in Python for C function with parameter unsigned char * with SWIG

Tags: python, c, swig

I have the following C function wrapped by Swig for Python:

```c
read(unsigned char *buffer...)
```

I've been trying to create a buffer, but I'm only getting a TypeError. What is the best way, in Python, to create a buffer for storing the string?

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: `unsigned char *buffer...` isn't legal c. What's the function you're trying to wrap really look like?

Comment: Very much aware. Was just implying that it is additional arguments, but the buffer is the only one that can't seem to map.  
```C
read(unsigned char *buffer, uint32_t amt, uint32_t *actualAmt)
```

Comment: Not enough information in your question, but see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22428292/235698) for examples of reading into buffers.

Comment: The neatest solution to this depends on the exact semantics of the rest of the arguments given to the function. What are `amt` and `actualAmt` for? Without knowing how does a C caller call this function it's impossible to suggest a neat way for a python caller to do the same.